# Horizontal boxes in article class

Tags: boxes, article

How can I have a box with multiple boxes inside like the following in the article class?

[image]

It should be at the beginning of the page on the left side.

Comment: Looks like a job for `tabular` to me.

Comment: At the beginning of all pages?

Comment: No, only one page and the size of the hole box should be smaller than two line spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Individuelle box sizes are also possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|*{10}{p{8mm}|}}\hline
\rule{0pt}{1.8\normalbaselineskip}
 & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```